# c# mvc how to map the root url to a specific view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an mvc app with a DefaultController which maps to index.cshtml
so

```
http://localhost:<port>/Default/Index
```

works fine.
but the default root page:

```
http://localhost:<port>/
```

is not mapped to anything.
How can I map it to my Default/Index?

Here is my RouteConfig.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace MVC5_HttpClientTest_F45
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `new { controller = "Home"` into `new { controller = "Default"`.

Comment: what are you expecting then??

Comment: @Silvermind - is this some kind of rule in MVC? If default controller name is set to 'HomeController' than this path localhost:53130 is not routed (the response is 'forbidden'). If default controller name is set to 'DefaultController' route path gets routed there. Why?

Comment: @FrenkyB When the url does not contain any information about a controller name: (`http://localhost/` is such an empty url), the route will go to the controller name that is defined as the default. The name of the controller does not matter, if you wanted to go to `MySuperDuperController` instead, you would create `new { controller = "MySuperDuper"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your Default Map route controller to

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Default",
   url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: omg, I had renamed Default to Home and then changed it back but forgot to change this. Thanks