# How to map the root url to swagger view in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi

My application is in .net core.

I want to map the root URL `http://localhost:<port>/` to swagger view.
I tried by setting the default route, as specified in below link, but it doesn't work.

[c# mvc how to map the root url to a specific view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26132022/c-sharp-mvc-how-to-map-the-root-url-to-a-specific-view)

I think it's because of I am using attribute routing. 
But is there any way, I can map root URL to Swagger view.

Comment: Can you post that code that didn't work for you?

Answer (score 1):

To map the root url you'll have to:

- Create a HomeController on your API project and add the following code.

  ```
  [Route("")]
  [HttpGet]
  [AllowAnonymous] (Only if you have authorization going on)
  public IActionResult Index()
  {
      return Redirect("/swagger/ui/index.html");
  }
  ```
- After that, you have to open the folder properties on your project and update the section profile on file launchSettings.json as follows.

```js
"profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "/",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "odin": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "http://localhost:5000/",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
```